# PHP - Get [0] value from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array in PHP 7:

Array ( [0] => 'Param1' [1] => "Value1" )

How can I get 'Param1' and "Value1" values?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$arr[0]` for Param1 and `$arr[1]` for Value1

Answer (score 3):

to access array values by key you'd do:

```
<?php 
    $array = ['product_id' => 100, 'product_name' => 'name'];

    //basic
    $firstParam = $array[$keyValue]

    //e.g.
    $id = $options['product_id'];

    //var_dumping the id will return 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array's name is `array`, then:

```
echo $array[0]; //Param1
echo $array[1]; //Value1
```